# How to set multiple JNDI names in Weblogic wlst Offline

Tags: weblogic, wlst

I want to add 2 jndi names to one data source.This is my code.

```
cd('/JDBCSystemResource/primelogDataSource/JdbcResource/primelogDataSource')
create('primelogDataSourceParams','JDBCDataSourceParams')
cd('JDBCDataSourceParams/NO_NAME_0')java.lang.String('abcDataSource','cdaDataSource'))
set('GlobalTransactionsProtocol', java.lang.String('None'))
```

This won't work. But if i add only one jndi name like below, it is working.

```
cd('JDBCDataSourceParams/NO_NAME_0')java.lang.String('abcDataSource'))
```

I  must mention that this is offline python script. I am looking for help.

Comment: try this sample code : `JNDINames="jndiName1,jndiName2" 
 cd('JDBCDataSourceParams/NO_NAME_0')  set("JNDIName", JNDINames)`

Comment: Tip: at the top in weblogic you have a 'record' button. Take a session, click the record button, do your changes, click the record button again and it will write a script to the filesystem that does the actions you recorded.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin This did't work for me. I used online wlst script to set the JNDINames instead of offline script.

Comment: @WesleyDeKeirsmaeker your tip was very helpful. Earlier i did't know about this method. Can you add this as an answer, Then I can select it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top in weblogic you have a 'record' button. Take a session, click the record button, do your changes, click the record button again and it will write a script to the filesystem that does the actions you recorded